# Time::Piece strptime has trouble with %X

Tags: date, perl, strptime

I'm trying to parse the following data using Time::Piece->strptime() in perl v5.26:

```
my $str = "Mon Feb 21 02:54:49 IST 2022";
my $time_zone = substr($str, 20, 3);
my $date_time = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%a %b %e %X $time_zone %Y");
print "Todays date/time is : $date_time";
```

But, when I execute the above code snippet, I get the following error:

```
Error parsing time at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Time/Piece.pm line 598.
```

I'm not sure what is it that I'm missing out, any help will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%X` without the final `AM/PM` only works at the end of a string.

```
my $str = "Mon Feb 21 IST 2022 02:54:49";
my $time_zone = substr($str, 11, 3);
warn $time_zone;
my $date_time = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%a %b %e $time_zone %Y %X");
print "Todays date/time is : $date_time";
```

or

```
my $str = "Mon Feb 21 02:54:49 AM IST 2022";
my $time_zone = substr($str, 23, 3);
my $date_time = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%a %b %e %X $time_zone %Y");
print "Todays date/time is : $date_time";
```

But my testing shows this behaviour is Perl version dependent, so maybe don't use `%X` (same as `%I:%M:%S %p`) at all and switch to `%T` (same as `%H:%M:%S`).

```perl
my $str = "Mon Feb 21 02:54:49 IST 2022";
my $time_zone = substr($str, 20, 3);
my $date_time = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%a %b %e %T $time_zone %Y");
print "Todays date/time is : $date_time";
```

Comment: I end up making the code work with 
```my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%a %b %d %T %Y");```
But. If I add $time_zone, like ```my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($str, "%a %b %d %T 
$time_zone %Y");```
it wont print the timezone..
Anything that we can do for it?

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a new question. You can link to the old one for context.